# Como accedo a la variable de una funcion en otra

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un gestor de imagen con descripciones en donde puedo modificar los textos de la imagen y el archivo de imagen.

La idea es poder guardar las modificaciones que realizo en mi base de datos, pero la forma que he encontrado es guardar únicamente si modifico la imagen. Si no modifico la imagen, no puedo guardar modificaciones de los textos.

Se me ocurrio poder acceder a la variable imagenPopup dentro de la funcion click y poder solucionar el problema, pero no se si es posible eso.

Quizá saben una mejor forma de realizar esto y no la estoy viendo.

Agradezco la ayuda!

**Les paso el código de JQUERY:**

```
/*=============================================
SUBIR IMAGEN
=============================================*/

$("#subirPopup").change(function(){

    var imagenPopup = this.files[0];

    /*=============================================
    VALIDAMOS EL FORMATO DE LA IMAGEN SEA JPG O PNG
    =============================================*/

    if(imagenPopup["type"] != "image/jpeg" && imagenPopup["type"] != "image/png"){

        $("#subirLogo").val("");

        swal({
              title: "Error al subir la imagen",
              text: "¡La imagen debe estar en formato JPG o PNG!",
              type: "error",
              confirmButtonText: "¡Cerrar!"
            });

    /*=============================================
    VALIDAMOS EL TAMAÑO DE LA IMAGEN
    =============================================*/

    }else if(imagenPopup["size"] > 2000000){

        $("#subirLogo").val("");

         swal({
              title: "Error al subir la imagen",
              text: "¡La imagen no debe pesar más de 2MB!",
              type: "error",
              confirmButtonText: "¡Cerrar!"
            });

    /*=============================================
    PREVISUALIZAMOS LA IMAGEN
    =============================================*/

    }else{

        var datosImagen = new FileReader;
        datosImagen.readAsDataURL(imagenPopup);

        $(datosImagen).on("load", function(event){

            var rutaImagen = event.target.result;

            $(".previsualizarPopup").attr("src", rutaImagen);

        })

    }

    /*=============================================
    GUARDAR CAMBIOS
    =============================================*/

    $("#guardarPopup").click(function(){

        var tituloPopup = $("#tituloPopup").val();

        var textoBotonPopup = $("#textoBotonPopup").val();

        var rutaBotonPopup = $("#rutaBotonPopup").val();    

        var datos = new FormData();
        datos.append("tituloPopup", tituloPopup);
        datos.append("textoBotonPopup", textoBotonPopup);
        datos.append("rutaBotonPopup", rutaBotonPopup);
        datos.append("imagenPopup", imagenPopup);

        $.ajax({

            url:"ajax/popup.ajax.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: datos,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(respuesta){

                if(respuesta == "ok"){

                    console.log(respuesta);

                    swal({
                      title: "Cambios guardados",
                      text: "¡La plantilla ha sido actualizada correctamente!",
                      type: "success",
                      confirmButtonText: "¡Cerrar!"
                    });

                }


            }

        })


    })

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo mas sencillo es declarar tu variable en el exterior de ambas funciones e inicializarla donde corresponda. En este caso en el interior de `$("#subirPopup").change();`

De esta forma podrias usarla en el interior de la funcion manejadora del evento `click();` pero debes asegurarte de que no se produzca dicho evento antes de entrar a la función manejadora del evento `change();` Pues si esto ocurre tu variable no tiene ningun valor...

```
//Declarar sin inicializar...
var imagenPopup;

$("#subirPopup").change(function(){

   //Inicializar...
   imagenPopup = this.files[0];

   etc... etc...
}

$("#guardarPopup").click(function(){

//Aqui si se ha ejecutado previamente la funcion anterior... puedes usar imagenPopup
   console.log(imagenPopup);

   etc... etc...
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me ha servido